# How to change the opening position of a file in photoshop CS

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I open up a file in Photoshop CS the upper left hand corner of the file is lined up all the way to left. The tool bar hides part of the file. So each and every single time I open a file I have to drag it to the position I want. How do I change this so that the upper left hand corner of the file is lined up to the upper right hand corner of the tool bar and set it as the default? I've included a link to a picture for clarity.

http://i772.photobucket.com/albums/yy9/mlswartz/open%20file%20photoshop_zpsbcllcx4b.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Photoshop for many years and, as far as I remember, the images opened in Photoshop have always been aligned at the center of the document's window.

From what I see in your image you are using floating windows and the images fill the whole window, so you can't tell if they are aligned right or left.

In Photoshop's Window menu, under Arrange, you can set the windows to consolidate to tabs, float or tile vertically and horizontally. I don't think there's a way to align them left or right, either than manually.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences,

Click Reset Preferences on quit

It'll all adjust to it's original state.

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some more explanation why your solution works with detail and an easy to follow instructions. eg:"It'll all adjust to it's original state which will place it where you want it",etc. I like the short answer but detail is god. If you feel your answer is correct do these things and re-edit. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser user9380008 and Thankyou for the answer.

Comment: It is in its original state. I want to change its original state.